# Sqlite error in Windows Phone 8 - tracker.exe and Winmd files are missing

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on Windows Phone 8 Application and I need to connect it with Sqlite database. I am following a tutorial which is below link.  http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

I am getting error as "tracker.exe is missing and Sqlite.winmd could not be found." Am I missing anything? Why I am getting this error. Any good links are also accepted with clear description in connecting Sqlite with Windows Phone. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add sqlite-net in your project from Manage NuGet packages and you can see Sqlite.cs and SqliteAsync.cs file in your project.

Step 1: Make a Class, This class is referred as table in your database.

```
    class TableName
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IndexNo { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String User { get; set; }
        public String LastEdit { get; set; }
    }
```

Step 2: Create database file, connect it with SQliteConnection and Create Table

```
    private async void CreateDatabase()
    {
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
        //Checking if database already exists
        try
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile storagefile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Database.sqlite");
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }
        //if not exists then creating database
        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            String str = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.sqlite");
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(str);
            conn.CreateTable<TableName>();

        }
    }
```

Step 3: Execute Queries

1. Insert Values

   ```
   conn.Execute("insert into TableName(Name,User,LastEdit) values(?,?,?)",val1, val2, val3);
   ```
2. Fetch DataBase

To get all data use

```
    var result = conn.Table<TableName>().ToList();
```

To get some Related Data use

```
    var result = conn.Table<TableName>().Where(x => x.User == "abc").ToList();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
      var name=item.Name;
      var user=item.User;
    }
```

Remember whenever you want to execute queries which affect database use conn.Execute statement and when you want to get values from database you should use conn.Table query just for ease. There are lot more method you will get in SQlite Library.
Also Remember to using SQlite;

For Further Details or for Samples [Visit Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671)

Good Luck

Comment: @madhukumar yes I'm a windows phone developer and you can contact me if you think I can help you someway but I've problem in installing skype on my desktop. However you can mail me on my mail id in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use sqlite-net version 1.0.7

[image]

Comment: Hi Amit, i used sqlite-net also. It is the problem of O.S. My problem is how to connect to this sqlite database and using them in my project. Thank u.

Comment: You mean you want code to create tables and exacute commands in database using sqlite?

Comment: Yes Amit. Any Links are appreciated.